# KIF 3.0 (XCTest) tests from command line

Tags: xcodebuild, xctest, kif, kif-framework

My KIF tests are running fine from within the xcode however, when I run those from command line with following command, KIF tests are failing however all other unit tests (XCTest) are passing. My command below,

> xcodebuild debug  -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace  -scheme sc -sdk
>   iphonesimulator

Answer (score 1):

Just add version to iphonesimulator, for example iphonesimulator**10.2**